# How do error bars change for variables squared?

Tags: statistics, error-propagation

Let's say I have some variable $\mu$ with an uncertainty estimate:

$$\mu = 2 \pm .5$$

Let's say I have another variable $\nu = \mu^2$. Is the uncertainty estimate in $\nu$ equal to the the uncertainty in $\mu$ squared, such that

$$\nu = 4 \pm .25$$

This does not seem to be right to me. What would be the appropriate way of getting the uncertainty in $\nu$?

Comment: $\mu = a \pm b$, then $\mu^2 = (a \pm b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 \pm 2 ab$, you're missing the extra term.

Comment: If $1.5 \le \mu \le 2.5$ then $2.25 \le \mu^2 \le 6.25$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncertainty can be written for a quantity :

$$ X=Y \pm u(Y) $$

Then taking the square you have

$$ (Y\pm u(Y))^2=Y^2\pm 2Yu(Y)+u(Y)^2$$

Or a the first order for maybe more sense

$$ (Y\pm u(Y))^2=Y^2\pm 2Yu(Y)$$
It is ok for you ?

Comment: what do $o(Y),o(Y^2)$ mean?  Note that if the new variable is a nonlinear function of the original one, the error induces a shift as well.  In fact, in error propagation, one usually assumes a first order linearisation, so that $(\mu \pm \delta)^2 = \mu^2 \pm 2\mu \delta + h.o.t$ where $h.o.t.$ stands for higher order terms which are neglected.

Comment: $o(Y)$ means the error on $y$. Here it causes no problem at all. Indeed we get $Yo(Y)=o(Y^2)$  even being non-linear it stays right because of the $(\mu + \delta)^2$ you've mentionned. It is right higher order are neglected

Comment: Do you have a reference for this notation? How does one derive $Yo(Y)=o(Y^2)$ ? To answer OP's question directly $\mu=2\pm0.5 \rightarrow \nu \sim 4\pm 2 \times (0.5)\times 2 =4\pm 2$

Comment: You're right. we have to keep that term. Thanks I modified it.

Comment: Fix the factor 2, delete the $u(y)^2$ ( because $u$ is the error bound and cannot be taken directly as a shift term) and I will upvote you.

Comment: What is the difference between this answer and the answer provided directly to my post? According to that one, the answer should be $\nu = 4.25 \pm 2$.

Comment: 1) you did not include the 2 in $2\times Y u(Y)$ .   2) the 0.25  bias is not really meaningful, since it is not clear how to interpret the $\pm u(Y)$ term. it is a random term,  perhaps representing the standard deviation. Anyway  wikipedia recommends just going to first order: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Non-linear_combinations